# LINQ query help needed for Intersect

Tags: linq-to-sql, subquery

LINQ gurus, I am looking for help to write a query...

I have a table with Person records, and it has a nullable ParentID column, so it is kind of self-referencing, where each record might have a Parent.

I am looking for unprocessed rows whose parent rows were processed. 
This SQL works fine:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Person
  where IsProcessed = 0 and
  ParentId in
  (
  select Id from Person 
  where IsProcessed = 1
  )
```

I tried a number of LINQ queries, but they failed. Now, I'm trying:

```
    var qParent = 
                from parent in db.Person
                where 
                parent.IsProcessed == true
                select parent.ID;

    var qChildren = from child in db.Person
                    where
                    child.IsProcessed == false
                    && child.ParentId.HasValue
                    select child.ParentId.Value;

    var q2 = qChildren.Intersect(qParent);
```

This yields SQL with a DISTINCT clause, for some reason, and I am baffled why DISTINCT is generated.

My main question is how to write LINQ for the SQL statement above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intersect is a *set* operation - it is meant to return a set of distinct elements from the intersection. It seems reasonable to me that it would use DISTINCT in the SQL. There could be multiple children with the same parent, for example - `Intersect` should only return that ID once.

Is there any reason you don't want to use a join here?

```
var query = from parent in db.Person
            where parent.IsProcessed
            join child in db.Person.Where(child => !child.IsProcessed)
               on parent.ID equals child.ParentId.Value
            select child;
```

Comment: yes, I agree that a join is the way to go.
I turned it around a bit to make it more logical to read:

var q = 
from child in db.Person
where !child.IsProcessed
join parent in db.Person
on child.ParentID.value equals parent.ID
where parent.IsProcessed
select child;

thanks a ton, Jon

Answer (score 0):

The query can be translated literally into :

```
var parentIds = db.Person.Where(x => x.IsProcessed)
                      .Select(x => x.Id)
                      .ToList();
var result = db.Person.Where(x => !x.IsProcessed && parentIds.Contains(x => x.Id))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks a lot Obalix. 
Your query works too, but may be less efficient than the join because of the parent toList() op, or maybe not.

I fixed the syntax error to be: parentIds.Contains(x.Id.value)
removing the repeat x =>.

Comment: Well, not much. The parent query is executed once (only contains IDs) then it gets put into the Linq to SQL and becomes `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE isprocessed = 0 && id in (1, 2, 3 ...)`. And this executes fairly quickly, but you obviously use the join solution too. Who dares to conradict Jon Skeet? Don't forget to accept the answer that you ar e happy with.